# AVAsset duration is not correct

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avasset

I have video in Mac player duration of video is 31 seconds. When I'm using it in my app and loading that file the duration of AVAsset is '28.03'.

```
AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoUrl];
Float64 time = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration);
```

Answer (score 6):

For some types of assets a duration is an approximation. If you need the exact duration (should be an extreme case) use:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @YES};
AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [URLAssetWithURL:videoUrl options:options];
```

You can find more informations in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Initialization_Options). Calculating the duration may take some time, so remember to use asynchronous loading:

```
[videoAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"duration"] completionHandler:^{
    switch ([videoAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"duration" error:nil]) {
        case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
            Float64 time = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration);
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            // other cases like cancellation or fail
            break;
    }
}];
```

You can find some more tips on using `AVFoundation` API in the video  [Discovering AV Foundation - WWDC 2010 Session 405](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/#405)

Comment: No. You should not use only on extreme case. You MUST use it all the time when you are working with compositions.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim - thanks for posting your comment about doing this when working with compositions, you sent me down the right path.